# margin is not working

Tags: html, css

I am setting `margin: 0 0 30px 0;` but it doesn't work. I can still see a gap on all sides of my `header` element.

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/HovhannesMkoyan/gn1ak0fo/):

```css
header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: .8em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: .8em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
}

nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}


/************************** COLORS ************************/

body {
  background-color: #343456;
  color: #999;
}

header {
  background: #6ab47b;
  border-color: #599a68;
}

nav {
  background: #599a68;
}

h1,
h2 {
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: #6ab47b;
}

nav a,
nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

nav a.selected,
nav a:hover {
  color: #32673f;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="treeHouse.html" id="logo">
      <h1>Hovhannes Mkoyan</h1>
      <h2>Designer</h2>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="treeHouse.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

When I set `margin: -10px 0px 30px 0px;`, the `top` gap disappears, but how can I get rid of it from all sides?

Comment: Try adding `body {margin:0;}` to remove the default margin - https://jsfiddle.net/67rcd7rh/

Comment: Make sure you close your `nav` tag, nothing to do with the margin issue but just saying, also @Anonymous is correct.

Comment: Use `* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}` as said in below answer. It will remove default browser margin and padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the padding around the header, simply add `margin:0` to the universal selector (*) like so:

**NOTE** Place this at the very top of your css file, on line 1

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

This will remove all the padding and all the margin on all elements unless you tell the element style to give it a padding or a margin.

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmda3vy9/1/)**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The site body has a default `8px` margin all around it, you can remove this by giving the `body` tag or a joker `*` (or both) the CSS style `margin: 0;`.

```css
*, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
#logo {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  margin: 15px 0;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: .8em;
}
h2 {
  font-size: .8em;
  margin: -5px 0 0;
  font-weight: 500;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 10px;
}
nav a {
  font-weight: 800;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}
/************************** COLORS ************************/

body {
  background-color: #343456;
  color: #999;
}
header {
  background: #6ab47b;
  border-color: #599a68;
}
nav {
  background: #599a68;
}
h1,
h2 {
  color: #fff;
}
a {
  color: #6ab47b;
}
nav a,
nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}
nav a.selected,
nav a:hover {
  color: #32673f;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <a href="treeHouse.html" id="logo">
      <h1>Hovhannes Mkoyan</h1>
      <h2>Designer</h2>
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="treeHouse.html" class="selected">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers actually put default styling on some elements. This is both useful and annoying in different situations. Its called `user agent stylesheet`

[image]

So you have to Use a  `master stylesheet` to clear out the default browser properties.

Here are Some Default HTML Browser Properties

body  --->             `margin:8px`

p ------->             `margin-top:5px , margin-bottom:4px`

h1,h2,h3.....h6 --->   `margin 20 to 25px`

Evenn ul,li,a, image, input, button all has some default Browser Stylesheet.

To Avoid or Override these properties We have to Use a master stylesheet. We call it as reset css, It Will look like this

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0
 }
```

}